# Get data in email body with Python

Tags: python, outlook, automation, task, win32com

To automate a task I need to get a code sent to me by e-mail in my outlook in order to log into a website. I am new to python, so I was wondering, how can I do it using the win32com module.

Thanks.

Comment: Probs start with some code that does what you want, then debug and refine until you have a finished product

Comment: Can you post an example of email body?

Answer (score 0):

You could use smtplib and email.MIME libreries:

This is an example to how send an email from/to a outlook email:

```
import smtplib
from email.mime.multipart import MIMEMultipart
from email.mime.text import MIMEText


strFrom = 'email@hotmail.com' 
strTo = 'email@hotmail.com'

msgRoot = MIMEMultipart('related')
msgRoot['Subject'] = 'Email subject'
msgRoot['From'] = strFrom
msgRoot['To'] = strTo

msgAlternative = MIMEMultipart('alternative')
msgRoot.attach(msgAlternative)

body='text, can be plain or html'

msgText_Total=MIMEText(body,'html')
msgAlternative.attach(msgText_Total)

s = smtplib.SMTP('SMTP.Office365.com:587')
s.ehlo()
s.starttls()
s.login('email@hotmail.com','password')
s.sendmail(strFrom, msgRoot["To"].split(","), msgRoot.as_string())
s.quit()
```

I hope this will helpful for you.